# MYSQL in AWS Athena

Tags: mysql, sql, select, amazon-athena

Using AWS Athena (so querying with MySql) I'm trying to retrieve information how many times the same IP has been logged. I have columns: timestamp, IP, country. I would like to count unique occurrences of each IP.

I'm trying with this query but results are wrong:

```
SELECT timestamp as Timestamp,
       count(httprequest.clientIp) as Count,
       httprequest.country as Country
FROM table_name
GROUP BY timestamp, httprequest.country
```

Thank you for helping achieving me this counter query.

EDIT:

Sample data:

```
{
    "timestamp":1610808650667,"httpRequest": 
               {"clientIp":"11.111.111.111",
                "country":"UK"}
}
```

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you want to get for it

Comment: Sorry for that, I've added sample data

Comment: You should read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/extracting-data-from-JSON.html

Comment: If you want to count occurrences of each IP, wouldn't you need to group by the IP too? When you say the results are wrong I doubt your sample data would show that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to know how many times a certain IP has been logged, the IP should be the only column in your `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   httprequest.clientIp, COUNT(*)
FROM     table_name
GROUP BY httprequest.clientIp
```